# Convergence of $x_{n}=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+1}}+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+2}}+\cdots+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$x_{n}=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+1}}+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+2}}+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+3}}+...+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+n}}.$$ Then $(x_{n})$ converges to

(A)$1$

(B)$0$

(C)$\frac{1}{2}$

(D)$\frac{3}{2}$

My Try:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}=\frac{n^2}{n^{3}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^6}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^{6}}}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^5}}})=0.$$
Am i right?

Comment: you should never forget that the term in the brackets is in the limit a sum of infintely many terms, In particular it is not even clear if the sum/series is bounded independent of $n$. A similar false proof is the following: $1=n/n=1/n + ... + 1/n = (1/n)(1+...+1)\to 0$. One additionally remark, the equality first equality is even false since on the left hand side is a limit and on the right hand side only the value of $x_n$ for fixed $n$ and this is never zero but converges to zero! (Un)fortunately notation is very important

Comment: Side note, term in brackets may be calculated to `n`, which results  in the whole limitation to 1, not 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following inequality:
$$
\frac{n.n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+n}}\leq \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+1}}+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+2}}+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+3}}+...+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+n}}\leq \frac{n.n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}+1}}
$$
Then take the limit of both sides and you can see the limit is 1.

Comment: This is called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Answer (score 0):

$$
x_{n}=\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}}}+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}}}+\cdots+\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}}} = n(\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^{6}}}) = \frac{n^3}{n^3} = 1
$$

This is how I solve this.